# Error Copying the Folder! Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Tags: powershell

For background I am trying to copy the contents of a directory that gets updated with files daily to SharePoint online where it will be accessed by many users from departments across the organization.  Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Error Message

'Error Copying the Folder! Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s):  "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."'

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extension\16\ISAP\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extension\16\ISAP\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"
  
#Function to Copy a Folder

Function Copy-SPOFolder([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFolderURL, [String]$TargetFolderURL)
{
    Try{
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
      
        #Copy the Folder
        $MoveCopyOpt = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($Ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
        Write-host -f Green "Folder Copied Successfully!"
    }
    Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Copying the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
  

#Set Config Parameters

$SiteURL="https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/US-LocationMaster/"
$SourceFolderURL="C:\US-Location Files\"
$TargetFolderURL="https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/US-LocationMaster/Documents/"
  
#Get Credentials to connect

$Cred= Get-Credential
  
#Call the function to Copy the Folder

Copy-SPOFolder $SiteURL $SourceFolderURL $TargetFolderURL
```

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER : I can't test this, as I don't have the assemblies, and I'm just doing this by eye.

Judging from my few minutes of [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee543738(v=office.15)) I think calling the `ExecuteQuery()` method is unnecessary in this scenario.

As it stands, I don't see the `$Ctx` having any query loaded, so I don't see the `ExecuteQuery()` method doing much.

when it comes to this bit

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($Ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt)
```

[Judging from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt844927(v=office.15)) it looks like it performs the actions we need, so I would remove `$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()` and see if the code does its thing correctly.

If that line instead creates an object, try using the `Load()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536388(v=office.15)) on `$Ctx`, then use the `ExecuteQuery()` method.

It'll look a a bit like this

```
Function Copy-SPOFolder([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFolderURL, [String]$TargetFolderURL)
{
    Try{
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
      
        #Copy the Folder
        $MoveCopyOpt = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions
        $Ctx.Load([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($Ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt))
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
        Write-host -f Green "Folder Copied Successfully!"
    }
    Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Copying the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```